# JQuery OR Condition CSS?

Tags: jquery, blueprint-css

I do this thing at lot of space so just want to check on what will be best practice in this case

```
if(ElementIsToBeShown)//This is java server side statement  
   .Options{  
   Display:block;   
 }else{  //ServerSide
  .Options{  
  Display:none;  
  }  
}
```

Or use JQuery.show and hide to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side is always better, because it'll work immediately, and even if JavaScript is turned off.

The method you show is fine.

If this is to globally hide a certain type of elements, another option is  giving the `body` tag a specific classname:

```
if(ElementIsToBeShown) //This is java server side statement   
 {
   <body class="hide_elements">
 }
 else
 {
   <body>
 }
```

(this is pseudo-code; you know what I mean)

and having the CSS contain the rule that if the body has that class, hide all elements of the class `.Options`:

```
body.hide_elements .Options { display: none }
```

this is nice because you can hard-code this into your CSS, and need to alter the body's class only. But as said, the method you show is fine as well.